# Cancel current touches in an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch, user-interaction

I am trying to cancel all current touches in a window/inside the entire app. I tried setting

```
window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
window.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But the touches that are active at the moment when I disable the user interaction are not cancelled. I also tried setting `alpha` to 0 and back to 1 and also setting `hidden` to `YES` and `NO` with no luck.

This:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

also didn't work.

Comment: Can you simply set a flag and just ignore touches in your touch handlers?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to those!

Comment: I would guess that you will need to intercept the touches early in the responder chain, perhaps by overriding hitTest.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[[yourSuperView subviews]
   makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)
   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE]];
```